# @media transform an off canvas nav

Tags: html, css, canvas, media-queries

I am attempting to transform an off canvas nav once the screen size hits a width of 600px. I have the nav bar toggled with a button that appears at 600px or less. I am trying to get the nav to close if you resize the screen to a width over 600px and then reopen iff the nav was already opened before resizing the screen. The ".show-nav #site-canvas" clauses in the two @media break points don't seem to do anything and i'm not sure why.

Here is the css

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px)
    {
       .toggle-nav
       {
         display: none;
       }

       #nav
       {
         display: block;
       }

       .show-nav #site-canvas
       {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
         transform: translateX(0);
       }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px)
    {
       .toggle-nav
       {
         display: block;
       }

       #nav
       {
         display: none;
       }

       .show-nav #site-canvas
       {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
         transform: translateX(300px);
       }
    }

    #site-wrapper 
    {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #site-canvas 
    {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
      transition: 300ms ease all;
    }

    #site-menu 
    {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: -320px;
      background: black;
    }

    #site-menu > .nav-pills > li
    {
      padding-left: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      list-style-type: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
    }

    #site-menu > .nav-pills > a
    {
      display: block;
    }

    .show-nav #site-canvas 
    {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
      transform: translateX(300px);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css order Try this **CSS**

```
    #site-wrapper 
    {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #site-canvas 
    {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
      transition: 300ms ease all;
    }

    #site-menu 
    {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: -320px;
      background: black;
    }

    #site-menu > .nav-pills > li
    {
      padding-left: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      list-style-type: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
    }

    #site-menu > .nav-pills > a
    {
      display: block;
    }

    .show-nav #site-canvas 
    {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
      transform: translateX(300px);
    } 
@media screen and (min-width: 601px)
    {
       .toggle-nav
       {
         display: none;
       }

       #nav
       {
         display: block;
       }

       .show-nav #site-canvas
       {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
         transform: translateX(0);
       }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px)
    {
       .toggle-nav
       {
         display: block;
       }

       #nav
       {
         display: none;
       }

       .show-nav #site-canvas
       {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
         transform: translateX(300px);
       }
    }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a bunch. Can you explain a bit why the order mattered?

Comment: The order CSS rules are important media queries should belowyhe default rules. if it is worked please accept my answer :)

Comment: That is lower styles overrule higher styles